# Get column numbers of dataframe where given condition holds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
raw_data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_data,
                  columns=["cA", "cB", "cC"])

wrong_indexes = df.loc[df['cA'] > 2 ]
print(wrong_indexes)
```

This prints:

```
   cA  cB  cC
1   4   5   6
```

Instead of this, I would like to only get a list of indexes at which this condition holds, like so:

```
[1]
```

Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wrong_indexes = df.loc[df['cA'] > 2 ].index.tolist()
```

Comment: Nice answer...  Just perfect. +1